# Golang. Как прочитать тело ответа из POST запроса: вместо html получается мусор

Tags: html, парсер, golang

Как прочитать информацию в теле ответа из POST запроса? Ответ должен приходить в виде html как будто.

Больше 10 часов не могу раскодировать или что с ним надо делать. Читаю в инете и не нахожу. Вот в каком виде приходит resp.Body:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
И вот то же самое на Python:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот код на Golang:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"
    //"math/rand"
    //"time"
)

func main() {
    MakeRequest("https://www.investing.com/instruments/Service/GetTechincalData")
}

func MakeRequest(myUrl string) {

    fmt.Println("URL:>", myUrl)

    form := url.Values{}
    form.Add("pairID","1062537")
    form.Add("period","3600")
    form.Add("viewType","normal")

    req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", myUrl, strings.NewReader(form.Encode())) 
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent","Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0")
    req.Header.Set("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
    req.Header.Set("Accept", "text/html")
    req.Header.Set("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate")
    req.Header.Set("Connection", "keep-alive")
    req.Header.Set("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")

    client := &http.Client{}
    resp, err := client.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    defer resp.Body.Close()

    fmt.Println("response Status:", resp.Status)
    fmt.Println("response Headers:", resp.Header)

    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Println("response Body:", string(body))



}
```

Comment: У вас есть два пути. Первое научить программу распаковывать gzip,  второе убрать заголовок Accept-Encoding. Могу предположить, что питон из коробки умеет распаковывать gzip. Это из-за того, что вы добавили заголовок Accept-Encoding, что говорит серверу отдать вам сжатую html страницу.

Comment: все верно. если пользователь явно указал `Accept-Encoding: gzip`, то оно не будет декодировано автоматически. либо укажите `Accept-Encoding:*`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тело ответа сжато `gzip`. Вам нужно обернуть `resp.Body` в `gzip.Reader`.

Добавьте в импорты `"compress/gzip"` и немного измените читателя:

```
    gz, err := gzip.NewReader(resp.Body)
    body, err := ioutil.ReadAll(gz)
```

В результате будет напечатано

```
<div class="newTechStudiesRight instrumentTechTab" id="techStudiesInnerWrap">
<div class="summary">Summary:<span class="neutral uppercaseText" title="">Neutral</span></div>
<div class="summaryTableLine"><span>Moving Averages:</span><span
...
```

Для гарантии вам следует проверять [содержимое заголовка `Content-Encoding`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding) и использовать `gzip` если там стоит `gzip`.

Сразу скажу, что помимо `gzip` там может быть `compress` и `deflate`, да ещё несколько сразу через запятую. Поэтому, чтобы упростить себе жизнь, не пишите ничего лишнего в `Accept-Encoding` - укажите там `gzip` и достаточно. Если сервер не умеет `gzip`, то он пришлёт вам текст без сжатия.

Comment: Благодарю) Огрооомное спасибо) а то 12часов потерял( ну это третий день работы с го.